# C++ set a char value to a string?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement, char

This outputs upper case 'S' or 'P' regardless of the users choice to type lower case or not.
The output works when I cout with the other statements in my code 
HOWEVER... I want to display STANDARD or PREMIUM in my final cout statement.

How can I change the value of the char to output either STANDARD or PREMIUM???

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

char meal;

cout << endl << "Meal type:  standard or premium (S/P)?  ";
cin >> meal;

meal = toupper(meal);
    if (meal == 'S'){
      meal = 'S';
  }

    else{
      meal = 'P';
}
```

I've tried meal = 'Standard' and meal = 'Premium'
It doesn't work.

Comment: `char`s are not `string`s and `string`s are not `char`s... `'Standard'` is neither (you're trying to define a string using char syntax). Decide which you want, and declare _two_ variables if you need!

Comment: `if (meal == 'S') { meal = 'S'; }` seems totally pointless.

Comment: Well I've tried meal = 'Standard' and it didn't work.  It only output the final letter 'd'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    char meal = '\0';
    cout << "Meal type:  standard or premium (s/p)?" << endl;;
    string mealLevel = "";
    cin >> meal;
    meal = toupper(meal);
    if (meal == 'S'){
        mealLevel = "Standard";
    }

    else{
        mealLevel = "Premium";
    }
    cout << mealLevel << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it works, but I don't understand why the values are set like *char meal = '\0'  (what is this for?)

Answer (score 1):

declare extra variable `string mealTitle;`, then do `if (meal == 'P') mealTitle = "Premium"`

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
        string s = "Premium";
        cout << s;
}
```

Comment: Tried this just now but still only getting output 'S' or 'P'

Comment: Did you try `cout << mealTitle`?

Comment: I had my variables all turned around.  I think I got it now thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the variable `meal` to be a string, because its type is a `char`. Just use another object with a different name:

```
std::string meal_type;
switch (meal) {
case 'P':
    meal_type = "Premium";
    break;
case 'S':
default:
    meal_type = "Standard";
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::string ask() {
  while (true) {
    char c;
    std::cout << "\nMeal type:  standard or premium (S/P)?  ";
    std::cout.flush();
    if (!std::cin.get(c)) {
      return ""; // error value
    }
    switch (c) {
    case 'S':
    case 's':
      return "standard";
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
      return "premium";
    }
  }
}
int main() {
  std::string result = ask();
  if (!result.empty()) {
    std::cout << "\nYou asked for " << result << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cout << "\nYou didn't answer.\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry I only know C++

Comment: How is what I wrote not C++?